# Are there any Project Mangement Training classes that include the PMP certification?

Tags: pmp, certification, training

I know there are multiple training classes for PMP but I am looking for classes that have the certification included in the training. Or if not, a voucher for the PMP certification.

Comment: This is fundmentally a "shopping" question, which is considered off-topic on most Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 4):

No, there are no classes that you come away with a PMP certification.

The PMP test is a proctored test under full observation conditions. You register for the test with a licensed test facility. You show up on the day of your test and sign in. You then put everything but your clothes into a locker. They will give you some loose paper and a writing implement. You can get water from a cooler there, they generally don't even allow water bottles in.

You are then taken into a locked test room (usually about classroom size with individual single person mini-cubes). The computer is locked down to just the test software. A calculator program is included or they hand you a physical calculator.

The test is timed and starts when you start. One pro tip is that they provide a 15 minute tutorial on how to use the computer and test software. Use this time to regurgitate all the formulas, process flows and such you memorized onto a sheet of paper.

The test ends when the timer ends or you indicate you are done.

Take your time! When you're done, take a break. Go out, go to the bathroom, get a drink. Then come back and review every single answer. Then hit "done".

You will then sit for what feels like an eternity while the computer crunches your test. It will then spit out a pass / fail and how you did in each of the major test areas. You won't ever get to find out which questions you got wrong.

There is a reason the PMP remains a highly respected certification. It is not easy to get.

Answer (score 0):

The certification classes just give you the prerequisite 35 pdus ( if they are REP ), rest of the exam fee you have to pay it yourself

Answer (score 0):

because i am using it by myself for PMP preparation, i recommend you the “PMP PrepCast by Cornelius Fichtner”.

It is a fully prerecorded (nearly 140 video and audio lessons!), self-paced online training course which also provides you the 35 contact hour certificate, which you will need for your PMP Application. 
You may have a look here: ☛  http://wren.cf/2t
To get a glimpse of what you could await, there is a free version available also:  Free Prep Cast - 
http://wren.cf/2u

Your Benefits!:
Here is what you will gain from using The PM PrepCast in your PMP Exam preparation:
★ Increase your chance of passing the PMP® Exam!. You will receive real-world examples to help you truly understand the PMP® exam concepts. Simple memorization won’t get you there.

★ Study anywhere and reduce your study time because you can maximize your day by listening anywhere your tablet or smart phone goes. For instance you can listen when you drive to work, when you are outside riding your bike, or watch a lesson over lunch, as you are sitting on the bus or when you are waiting in line at the post office. It’s the anytime study miracle!

★ You hear everyday English and not the very difficult to understand language from A Guide to the Project Management Body of Knowledge (PMBOK® Guide) - Fifth Edition, Project Management Institute, Inc., 2013.

★ You hear 10 lessons on Applied PMP® Concepts, based on student and expert feedback. These interviews with experts translate the concepts into everyday project management situations that you can relate to.

★ You hear from a number of recent PMP® exam takers: Learn their best practices on how to apply, study and pass the exam the first time.

★ It's simple to get through – You’ll find that the 47 processes and 10 knowledge areas from the PMBOK® Guide are not as difficult as they may seem.

★ You will understand Earned Value Techniques and be able to answer questions about them confidently.

★ You learn the concept, tools & techniques that are not covered in the PMBOK® Guide but required for the exam without having to read dozens of other books.

★ You maximize your efforts with our valuable PMP® Exam Study Tips.

★ It's mobile! Carry The PM PrepCast with you as your "Personal PMP® Trainer" whenever you want to study, wherever you go.

★ Your studies will be more enjoyable and go smoother & faster, but most of all... they will be easier! It's guaranteed!

Please don't hesitate to contact me, if you have any further questions or if I may assist you anyway.
Best of luck!

Regards,

Markus

*) I am an affiliate partner of prepcast.com; some of the provided links may be affiliate links.

Comment: I don't think this answer's OP's question; the PMP exam is not included in Mr. Fichtner's class.